# Fit canvas to viewport but keep image resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, there's plenty resources online on how to resize a canvas and how to scale an image into it.

*However*, what I actually want is to

- take an image that's larger than the viewport
- stick it in a canvas that *does* fit into the viewport
- edit it there
- save the result without losing any of the image resolution

E.g. let's say I have a 5120×2880 image of a maze but only a 800x600 viewport (extreme example).

I want to display the image in the 800x600 viewport to allow the user to draw a path through the maze onto the image.

But if the user then saves the solved maze with their path, I want the picture to have the full 5120x2880 resolution.

What's the most efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The size of the canvas and the canvas element are different.
You will have to scale the coordinates to draw.
I have drawn lines so you can see the automatic scaling of the canvas to fit the container.
Example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var w = 5120, h = 2880;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  var x = 0, y = 0;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);

  var down = true;
  var change_y = true;
  var ini_x = x;
  var change_dir = false;

  while( true ){

      if( change_y ){
        y = ( down )? y + 20 : y - 20;
      }else{
        x = (x == ini_x)? ini_x + 20 : ini_x;
      }
      change_y = !change_y;

      if( change_dir ){
        x += 20;
        ini_x = x;
        if( x > w ){
          break;
        }
      }

      if( y >= h || y <= 0 ){
          if(!change_dir){
            down = !down;
          }
          change_dir = !change_dir
      }

      ctx.lineTo(x, y);

  }
  ctx.stroke();
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = c.toDataURL();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="5120" height="2880" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></canvas>
<br />
<p>In PNG:</p>
<img />
```

Curiosity:
Saving this image from chrome (536,162 bytes) weighs more than from firefox (348,814 bytes).